inner join with pagination and sorting
I have 2 tables:
CREATE TABLE account (
  id INT
);

CREATE TABLE device (
  id INT,
  account_id INT,
  token text
);

I want to display on my webpage table with users and their all device tokens. Table should support filtering, pagination and sorting. If i want to filter by device token: '%BIZ%', I want to display contacts with all their devices if at least one of them contains the '%BIZ%' keyword.
This is working example for first page of 5 contacts, with '%BIZ%' device token filter keyword, sorted by device token desc:
with cte as
(
  select
    a.id
    from account a
  inner join device d on d.account_id = a.id
  where d.token like 'BIZ%'
  group by a.id
  order by max(d.token) desc
  offset 0 rows
  fetch first 5 rows only
)

select
  cte.id,
  d.token
from cte
inner join device d on d.account_id = cte.id
order by d.token desc

I am wondering if there is any simpler way to do that, for example without double order by. Do you have any suggestion?
Example code: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vZCNfgvppXhmnz8sHbaWda/8

I added some data to your test data for the case when one row for an account meets the conditions of the token filter, but you need to show all the rows of this account.
See example
Without pagination
select * 
from device d
-- inner join account a on a.id=d.account_id -- if needed
where d.account_id in( select distinct account_id
                       from device d2
                       where d2.token like 'BIZ%')
order by d.account_id,d.token




id
account_id
token




1
1
BIZ-111


2
1
BIZ-333


3
1
BIZ-555


5
2
BIZ-666


4
2
BIZ-777


6
3
BIZ-999


7
4
BIZ-222


10
7
BIZ-888


11
8
BIZ-444


12
8
OnZ-444



select * 
from device d
where d.account_id in( select distinct account_id
                       from device d2
                       where d2.token like 'BIZ%')
order by d.account_id,d.token
offset 0 rows
fetch first 5 rows only




id
account_id
token




1
1
BIZ-111


2
1
BIZ-333


3
1
BIZ-555


5
2
BIZ-666


4
2
BIZ-777



Next page
...
offset 5 rows
fetch first 5 rows only




id
account_id
token




6
3
BIZ-999


7
4
BIZ-222


10
7
BIZ-888


11
8
BIZ-444


12
8
OnZ-444



fiddle

This is not exactly what I wanted. For example in this case:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vZCNfgvppXhmnz8sHbaWda/10
fetch first 3 rows only means I want to get 3 accounts with all their devices, when at least 1 of them contains the fragment BIZ. Which means, that For this input I should get 9 rows in the query result
